# Pandas left join with duplicates

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas data frame like

```
A = pd.DataFrame({'Name' : ['A', 'A','A'], 'Value' : [1,2,3]})
and another DataFrame 
B = pd.DataFrame({'Name': ['A', 'C', 'D', 'A', 'E', 'A'], 'Value1' :[1,2,3,4,5,6]})
```

When I merge these I get

```
A.merge(B, how='left', on='Name')
```

```
In [4]: A.merge(B, how='left', on='Name')
Out[4]: 
  Name  Value  Value1
0    A      1       1
1    A      1       4
2    A      1       6
3    A      2       1
4    A      2       4
5    A      2       6
6    A      3       1
7    A      3       4
8    A      3       6
```

Anyway to do this merge in a way such that first row with 'A' will match only with first row with 'A' in B, and second with second and third with third.
Final output like

```
  Name  Value  Value1
0    A      1       1
1    A      2       4
2    A      3       6
```

Thanks,

I tried doing left merge. I wasnt expecting anything different, but I am looking for a better way to do this.

Doing Inner join doesnt help either

```
A.merge(B, how='inner', on='Name')

  Name  Value  Value1
0    A      1       1
1    A      1       4
2    A      1       6
3    A      2       1
4    A      2       4
5    A      2       6
6    A      3       1
7    A      3       4
8    A      3       6
```

Comment: Apply inner join `A.merge(B, how='inner', on='Name')`

Comment: Inner join gives the same answer.

Answer (score 7):

Deduplicate with [`groupby.cumcount`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html) and pass it to `merge` as secondary key:

```
A.merge(B, how='left',
        left_on=['Name', A.groupby('Name').cumcount()],
        right_on=['Name', B.groupby('Name').cumcount()]
       )#.drop(columns='key_1')
```

Output:

```
  Name  key_1  Value  Value1
0    A      0      1       1
1    A      1      2       4
2    A      2      3       6
```

Answer (score 0):

You are requesting something that is not actually a join.

You can do something like this however:

```
pd.concat([A, B[B.Name == "A"].reset_index().Value1], axis=1)
```